# Copying struct Array into another struct array (GLKVector)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, struct, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I try to copy the content of vertexDataTextured ArmandDeBrignac [] array into vertexDataTextured MeshVertexData[] array. But it doesn't work.... I think the problem is in the struct method, there are GLKvector elements..... ?

This is my header-File:

```
struct vertexDataTextured
{
    GLKVector3      vertex;
    GLKVector3      normal;
    GLKVector2      texCoord;
};
typedef struct vertexDataTextured vertexDataTextured;
typedef vertexDataTextured* vertexDataTexturedPtr;


vertexDataTextured MeshVertexData[] = {}; 

vertexDataTextured ArmandDeBrignac[] = {
    {/*v:*/{-0.979979, -2.383373, -1.142941}, /*n:*/{0.000000, -0.725242, -0.688467}, /*t:*/{0.794971, 0.247112}},
    {/*v:*/{-0.859054, -2.367034, -0.829303}, /*n:*/{0.023591, -0.999512, 0.019593}, /*t:*/{0.786435, 0.224949}},
    {/*v:*/{-1.056731, -2.383373, -1.142941}, /*n:*/{-0.337657, -0.631642, -0.697836}, /*t:*/{0.800393, 0.247114}},
    {/*v:*/{-0.979979, -2.117816, -1.142941}, /*n:*/{0.000000, 0.500198, -0.865902}, /*t:*/{0.645127, 0.391262}},
    {/*v:*/{-0.979979, -2.383373, -1.142941}, /*n:*/{0.000000, -0.725242, -0.688467}, /*t:*/{0.663889, 0.391205}},
    {/*v:*/{-1.056731, -2.383373, -1.142941}, /*n:*/{-0.337657, -0.631642, -0.697836}, /*t:*/{0.663906, 0.396627}},
    {/*v:*/{-0.993670, -2.036772, 0.915066}, /*n:*/{-0.771722, 0.588244, 0.241585}, /*t:*/{0.293949, 0.430232}},
};


@interface FlaschenManager : NSObject

-(void) getFlaschenID: (NSString* ) Name andTexture: (NSString*) path;

@end
```

and my .m File

```
@implementation FlaschenManager

-(void) getFlaschenID: (NSString* ) Name andTexture: (NSString*) path
{

    if ([Name isEqualToString:@"ArmandDeBrignac"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",Name);

        MeshVertexData[0].vertex.v[0]=ArmandDeBrignac[0].vertex.v[0];
      //  MeshVertexData[] = ArmandDeBrignac[];

    } else if ([Name isEqualToString:@"Hennessy"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ ", Name);
        FlaschenName = Name;
    }
} 
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like this

```
vertexDataTextured ArmandDeBrignac[] = {
    {/*v:*/GLKVertex3Make(-0.979979, -2.383373, -1.142941), /*n:*/GLKVertex3Make(-0.979979, -2.383373, -1.142941), /*t:*/GLKVertex2Make(-0.979979, -2.383373)
}
```

also you probably want to rather go

```
MeshVertexData[0].vertex = ArmandDeBrignac[0].vertex;
```

if you are trying to access index 0 of vertex then use its xyz components instead

```
MeshVertexData[0].vertex.x = ArmandDeBrignac[0].vertex.x;
```

have not tested this at all, but its a suggestion

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
        
Now it works to copy the elements! 

But there is a new Problem, if i copy the above code in my project i get a ARC Semantic Issue failure.... with another Array?... 
Because i do not alloc memory for my new struct array?

Comment: you will probably need to find out the size of the struct using `sizeof()` then malloc the new array, and then assign the values